# How to set 24-hours format for date on java?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have been developing Android application where I use this code:

```
Date d=new Date(new Date().getTime()+28800000);
String s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(d);
```

I need to get date after 8 hours from current moment, and I want that this date has 24-hours format, but I don't know how I can make it by SimpleDateFormat. I also need that date has `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS` format.

Comment: what is your expected output with example ?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This will give you the date in 24 hour format.

```
    Date date = new Date();
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + 8);
    System.out.println(date);
    SimpleDateFormat simpDate;
    simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(simpDate.format(date));
```

Comment: I don't have enough time to test it, but someone told "If you use kk you will get results like 24:30 but if you use HH you can get it like 00:30" [Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078488/421467]. Is that true?

Comment: setHours is deprecated.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that Java reports midnight as 24:00 instead of the standard 00:00.

Comment: I tried only kk pattern and it works.

Answer (score 110):

for 12-hours format:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatArrivals = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.UK);
```

for 24-hours format:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatArrivals = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.UK);
```

Comment: why is this not marked as the correct answer..?
why add things manually and then test it?

Comment: This is the best approach because midnight is correctly reported as 00:00 and not 24:00.

Answer (score 20):

```
Date d=new Date(new Date().getTime()+28800000);
String s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(d);
```

HH will return 0-23 for hours.

kk will return 1-24 for hours.

See more here: [Customizing Formats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

use method **setIs24HourView(Boolean is24HourView)** to set time picker to set 24 hour view.

Comment: This is still the most correct answer.  I will edit to make it more clear, as I wasn't sure exactly what you were saying.  Also, the link in the above answer explains as well.

Comment: @jeet what is more common, 0-23 or 1-24?

Comment: @simgineer I have seen 0-23 in all cases that I remember (I don't ever recall seeing something like 24:30).

Answer (score 11):

Use HH instead of hh in formatter string

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

```
Instant.now()                                        // Capture current moment in UTC.
       .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )            // Lop off any fractional second.
       .plus( 8 , ChronoUnit.HOURS )                 // Add eight hours.
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )    // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone). Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
       .format(                                      // Generate a `String` object representing textually the value of the `ZonedDateTime` object.
           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" )
                            .withLocale( Locale.US ) // Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms used in localizing the text being generated. 
       )                                             // Returns a `String` object.
```

> 23/01/2017 15:34:56

## java.time

FYI, the old [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of java.time is back-ported to Java 6, Java 7, and Android (see below).

### `Instant`

Capture the current moment in UTC with the `Instant` class.

```
Instant instantNow = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34:56.789Z

If you want only whole seconds, without any fraction of a second, truncate.

```
Instant instant = instantNow.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34:56Z

### Math

The `Instant` class can do math, adding an amount of time. Specify the amount of time to add by the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum, an implementation of [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html).

```
instant = instant.plus( 8 , ChronoUnit.HOURS );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T20:34:56Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see that same moment through the lens of a particular region’s wall-clock time, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-23T15:34:56-05:00[America/Montreal]

### Generate string

You can generate a String in your desired format by specifying a formatting pattern in a `DateTimeFormatter` object.

Note that **case matters** in the letters of your formatting pattern. The Question’s code had `hh` which is for 12-hour time while uppercase `HH` is 24-hour time (0-23) in both `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` as well as the legacy `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The formatting codes in java.time are similar to those in the legacy `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same. Carefully study the class doc. Here, `HH` happens to work identically.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale( Locale.US );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

#### Automatic localization

Rather than hard-coding a formatting pattern, consider letting *java.time* fully localize the generation of the `String` text by calling [`DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime(java.time.format.FormatStyle)).

And, by the way, be aware that time zone and `Locale` have *nothing* to do with one another; orthogonal issues. One is about *content*, the meaning (the wall-clock time). The other is about *presentation*, determining the human language and cultural norms used in presenting that meaning to the user.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-01-23T12:34:56Z" );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );  // Notice that time zone is unrelated to the `Locale` used in localizing.
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );

DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );  // The locale determines human language and cultural norms used in generating the text representing this date-time object.
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-23T12:34:56Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-24T01:34:56+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]
>
> output: mardi 24 janvier 2017 à 01:34:56 heure avancée de la Nouvelle-Zélande

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

Update: The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) makes this kind of work much easier.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime later = DateTime.now().plusHours( 8 );
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" );
String laterAsText = formatter.print( later );

System.out.println( "laterAsText: " + laterAsText );
```

When run…

```
laterAsText: 19/12/2013 02:50:18
```

Beware that this syntax uses **default time zone**. A better practice is to use an explicit DateTimeZone instance.

Comment: Androiders: `Instant` requires API level 26.

Comment: @VonSchnauzer For Android before 26, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects linked in my bullet labeled “Android”.

Answer (score 5):

Try below code

```
    String dateStr = "Jul 27, 2011 8:35:29 PM";
    DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
       date = readFormat.parse( dateStr );
    } catch ( ParseException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String formattedDate = "";
    if( date != null ) {
    formattedDate = writeFormat.format( date );
    }

    System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Good Luck!!!

Check for various [formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

All u need do is to change the lowercase 'hh' in the pattern to an uppercase letter 'HH'

for Kotlin:

`val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") val currentDate = sdf.format(Date())`

for java:

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss") Date currentDate = sdf.format(new Date())`

Answer (score 1):

### [`LocalDateTime#plusHours`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusHours-long-)

`LocalDateTime` is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced with *Java-8* as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

Use `LocalDateTime#plusHours` to get a copy of this `LocalDateTime` with the specified number of hours added.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ZoneId.systemDefault() returns the timezone of your JVM. It is also the
        // default timezone for date-time type i.e.
        // LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()) is same as LocalDateTime.now().
        // Change the timezone as per your requirement e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(ldt);

        LocalDateTime after8Hours = ldt.plusHours(8);
        System.out.println(after8Hours);

        // Custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfTimeFormat24H = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfTimeFormat12h = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(dtfTimeFormat24H.format(after8Hours));
        System.out.println(dtfTimeFormat12h.format(after8Hours));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-01-07T15:24:52.736612
2021-01-07T23:24:52.736612
07/01/2021 23:24:52
07/01/2021 11:24:52 PM
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Using legacy API:**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentDateTime = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(currentDateTime);

        // After 8 hours
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        Date after8Hours = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println(after8Hours);

        // Custom formats
        SimpleDateFormat sdf24H = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // Change the timezone as per your requirement e.g.
        // TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London")
        sdf24H.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf12h = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        sdf12h.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        System.out.println(sdf24H.format(after8Hours));
        System.out.println(sdf12h.format(after8Hours));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Thu Jan 07 15:34:10 GMT 2021
Thu Jan 07 23:34:10 GMT 2021
07/01/2021 23:34:10
07/01/2021 11:34:10 PM
```

### Some important notes:

1. A date-time object is supposed to store the information about date, time, timezone etc., **not about the formatting**. You can format a date-time object into a **`String`** with the pattern of your choice using date-time formatting API.

   - The date-time formatting API for the modern date-time types is in the package, `java.time.format` e.g. `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`, `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` etc.
   - The date-time formatting API for the legacy date-time types is in the package, `java.text` e.g. `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`, `java.text.DateFormat` etc.
2. The `java.util.Date` object is not a real date-time object like the [modern date-time types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html); rather, it represents the milliseconds from the `Epoch of January 1, 1970`. When you print an object of `java.util.Date`, its `toString` method returns the date-time in the JVM's timezone, calculated from this milliseconds value. If you need to print the date-time in a different timezone, you will need to set the timezone to `SimpleDateFormat` and obtain the formatted string from it.
3. The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

   - For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
   - If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Date d=new Date(new Date().getTime()+28800000);
String s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm:ss").format(d);
```

here 'kk:mm:ss' is right answer, I confused with Oracle database, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDate24Hrs = (String) DateFormat.format(
            "MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss", calendar.getTime());
Log.i("DEBUG_TAG", "24Hrs format date: " + currentDate24Hrs);
```