# Converting datetime to string, wrong hours

Tags: java, android, datetime, format

I am doing like this in my android app (java):

```
String sdt_ = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd  HH:mm", dt_).toString();
```

but I got this

```
01-16 14:31:13.308: D/ThS(25810): dt_ = Wed Jan 16 13:28:00 GMT+00:00 2013
01-16 14:31:23.758: D/ThS(25810): sdt_ = 20130116  HH:28
```

if I change HH to hh I will get this

```
sdt_ = 20130116  01:28
```

**but I need this**

```
sdt_ = 20130116  13:28
```

Comment: Try DateFormat.format("'yyyyMMdd'  'HH:mm'", dt_); i added '

Comment: :) result is 01-16 15:04:21.818: D/ThS(29811): dt_ = yyyyMMdd  HH:mm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i don't know, what is wrong with your code, but this code works for me:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd  HH:mm");
String sdt = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
System.out.println(sdt);
```

EDIT:

later I found out that your original code should work with this:

```
String sdt_ = DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd  kk:mm", dt_).toString();
```

apparently, android.text.format.DateFormat doesn't use 'H' constraint and uses 'k' instead of it! see this question for more details: [How to set 24-hours format for date on java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907509/how-to-set-24-hours-format-for-date-on-java)

Comment: see my other answer, if you still want to use android.text.format.DateFormat :-)

Answer (score 4):

This will do it for you:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd  HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
String sdt_ = sdf.format(dt_);
```

Comment: thank you, it is working (with or without Locale.getDefault())

Comment: It does work without `Locale.getDefault()`, but if you are using Eclipse it will show you a lint warning and ask you to provide a locale to allow local date formatting. So explicitly setting the default locale is the same as omitting it.

Comment: yes I saw this hint, now I know how to use default locale, thank you

Answer (score 4):

You used hh in your `SimpleDateFormat` pattern. Thats the 12 hour format. Use kk instead, that gives you the hours of the day in a 24 hour format.See [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I do not see any 'kk' by your link . I used HH in my pattern.

Comment: @Foenix see in the table  k hour in day (1-24) (Number) 24