# Calendar gives -12 hours back

Tags: android, android-date

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String myDateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", c.getTime());

dateTv.setText(myDateString);
```

The output is:

2014-02-13 04:31

The hour is actually not 04, it is 16, i mean it is after noun, not after midnight (4 in the morning) if you know what i mean.

Why is it happening and how coul i fix it?

**E D I T:**

For the lovely -1 voters:

As somebody suggested:

```
  String myDateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", c.getTime());
```

This solution gives me this exact String:

2014-02-13 HH:45

YES. There are 2 'H' characters in my hours. It is exactly a H character, not a number.

Comment: Did you tried to replace "hh" by "kk" ? Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7078488/2065418

Comment: Add this as an anwer and i will accept it.

Comment: +1 to both for perfect argument ..HH  shows only char "HH" and kk works fine here as i tested..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace  "hh" by "kk" like below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String myDateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm", c.getTime());

dateTv.setText(myDateString);
```

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078488/2065418

Answer (score 5):

use `HH`

`hh` refers to hours with the use of PM and AM. of which you do not display

```
String myDateString = (String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", c.getTime());
```

As per the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> H = hour in day (0-23)
>
> h  = hour in am/pm (1-12)

Edit: There appears to be some kind of issue with `H` not being supported on API below 17, so it is preferred to use `kk` which is infact the proper `HH` implementation.

[Up to API level 17, only {@code adEhkMmszy} were supported. Note that this class incorrectly implements {@code k} as if it were {@code H} for backwards compatibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16764435/940834)

Comment: I believe that using `aaa` would show you the AM / PM on the end. - `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aaa"`

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi I notice from your comments that `kk` is working but `HH` does not. If you read through the documentation i linked, you will see that `kk` and `HH` are practically the same thing, except one is 0-23 vs 1-24. to whether you want midnight displayed as 24:00 or 00:00 i assume. As is `KK` the same as `hh` with the slight varience. The fact you get `HH` in string instead, is not functioning correctly. (`HH` is the norm, not `kk`)

Comment: @AdamVarhegyi With some digging it seems to be an API bug. `H` has since been supported on API 17 and above. and `k` is implemented as if it is `H` for backward compatibility.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763968/android-text-format-dateformat-hh-is-not-recognized-like-with-java-text-simple